# Detect the file format [Pentaho]

Tags: etl, pentaho

I have two types of files with 2 types of column formats.

I would like to take input of different files of 2 formats and detect the format of each of the files, in order to send them on 2 data tables depending on the format.

To detect these two formats, you have to read the first line which corresponds to the header.
There are two possible headers.

I don’t know how to proceed, I tried several methods (shell script) without result.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if the file is a pdf, docs etc or you want to check the computer file system?

Comment: @Tiberius No, you have to read the first line which corresponds to the header.
There are two possible headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata injection.

You create a transformation reading the file and just the first line, without considering delimiters for the fields, just the first line complete.

Then you use the **Split field to rows** step to get columns of your file, so you determine which type of the two files you are reading.

You'll need to add some more information probably depending of the file, but once you have all you need, you can inject that information (metadata) to a second transformation that just have the bare basics or the things both files have in common, and you inject the metadata for the things that are different for these two files.